# Access forbidden! xampp on osx with custom directory?

Tags: macos, apache, xampp

As you can see on the below picture, I tried to add `require all granted` and `allow from all`, but both didn't work.

The error is 403. The exact text is:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

I am on osx and just downloaded the newest xampp version and reinstalled it and even tried different directories. I can't get it to work. There are a lot of answers to this question but most of them are "add require all granted" and "add allow from all" to the directory in your `httpd.conf`.

The rights for the entire directory are 777, I double checked that as well.

Does anyone have a clue how that could be?

[image: httpd conf]

Edit: Solution was to set read permission every folder in the path, not just the one where the files sit.

Comment: Make sure that the http server process (the apache process, so which user account?) has exec and read access to _all_ files up to and including the configured folder.

Comment: And for further questions: please do _not_ post pictures of code! That is a clear "no no!" here on SO. Post your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do not mix Allow/Require directives in 2.4, use Require only. Also, make sure you are accessing that directory with the url you are requesting, whatever that is. Require all granted will be enough *if you are really accessing that directory*. Otherwise check/show error.log from apache. And never set 777 permissions for directories, apache just needs Search permissions for directories and read for files.

Comment: Wow, it works. The problem was that the highest folder(Google Drive) had no read permission. I thought read permission on the exact folder are enough. Wrong thinking. Thank you ezra, would you put that into an answer?